# spark naive bayes prediction analysis

Tags: apache-spark, machine-learning, apache-spark-mllib, naivebayes

I have used Naive Bayes for Text Classification

Below is the link I used for understanding Naive Bayes

https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2015/09/naive-bayes-explained/

Though I got good prediction results , I was not able to understand the reason for the failure cases

I measured the probability of the features using predictProbabilities to understand the reason for 
in correct prediction

Below is my understanding based on which I am trying to find why predictions are wrong in some cases

Assume my test data is like below  ( I have around 100000 records for training )

```
Text                                      Classification
There is a murder in town                 - HIGH SEVERITY
The old women was murdered                - HIGH SEVERITY
Boy was hit by ball in street             - LOW SEVERITY
John sprained his ankle while playing     - LOW SEVERITY
```

Now when I do a prediction for below sentence
"There is a murder in city" - I expect the model to predict HIGH SEVERITY. 
But at times the model predicts LOW SEVERITY

I pulled up all text which has same words and tried to figure out why this is happening . 
If I compute the probability manually using the formula in https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2015/09/naive-bayes-explained/, it should have been predicted correctly .
But I could not find any clue why the prediction is going wrong.

Kindly let me know if I am missing any critical information

Code Snippet Added Below

My Training Data Frame consists of three columns "id" , "risk", "label"

The text is already lemmetized using stanford NLP

```
    // TOKENIZE DATA

            regexTokenizer = new RegexTokenizer()
                      .setInputCol("text")
                      .setOutputCol("words")
                      .setPattern("\\W"); 

            DataFrame tokenized = regexTokenizer.transform(trainingRiskData);

    // REMOVE STOP WORDS

            remover = new StopWordsRemover().setInputCol("words").setOutputCol("filtered");

            DataFrame stopWordsRemoved = remover.transform(tokenized);

// COMPUTE TERM FREQUENCY USING HASHING

        int numFeatures = 20;
        hashingTF = new HashingTF().setInputCol("filtered").setOutputCol("rawFeatures")
                .setNumFeatures(numFeatures);
        DataFrame rawFeaturizedData = hashingTF.transform(stopWordsRemoved);

IDF idf = new IDF().setInputCol("rawFeatures").setOutputCol("features");
        idfModel = idf.fit(rawFeaturizedData);

        DataFrame featurizedData = idfModel.transform(rawFeaturizedData);

JavaRDD<LabeledPoint> labelledJavaRDD = featurizedData.select("label", "features").toJavaRDD()
                .map(new Function<Row, LabeledPoint>() {

                    @Override
                    public LabeledPoint call(Row arg0) throws Exception {
                        LabeledPoint labeledPoint = new LabeledPoint(new Double(arg0.get(0).toString()),
                                (org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.Vector) arg0.get(1));
                        return labeledPoint;
                    }
                });

NaiveBayes naiveBayes = new NaiveBayes(1.0, "multinomial");
        NaiveBayesModel naiveBayesModel = naiveBayes.train(labelledJavaRDD.rdd(), 1.0);
```

Once the training model is built , test data is passed through the same transformations and prediction is done using below code
Column 3 is label in test data frame.
Column 7 is features in test data frame

```
LabeledPoint labeledPoint = new LabeledPoint(new Double(dataFrameRow.get(3).toString()),
                        (org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.Vector) dataFrameRow.get(7));

double predictedLabel = naiveBayesModel.predict(labeledPoint.features());
```

Comment: I hope you have already done common preprocessing of NLP like stemming, punctuation removal, stop words, common words removal etc.

Comment: Below are the transformations done .  Lemmetization using Stanford NLP ,  Stop Words Removal using Spark , Hashing TF and IDF using Spark before training the model in Naive Bayes

Comment: Can you post your code snippet concerning the work flow ?

Comment: Update the code snippet to the question

Comment: The workflow seems ok for me beside for the number of features. You are aware that you are setting 20 features among the eventual thousands that you should have in your 100000 training records.

Comment: Thanks for reviewing the code and providing feedback . 
I will try to increase the number of features and test